# Error on Rails app: Cannot stat '/path/to/app/current/passenger_wsgi.py': Permission denied (errno=13)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, passenger

I've encountered something very strange.

I've had a Rails app running on a nginx server on Centos 7 for over a year now, and it always worked. I checked back after a few months and I got this 500 error:

```
*1 Cannot stat '/path/to/app/current/passenger_wsgi.py': Permission denied (errno=13)
```

It can't be an incorrect install as it worked for a year and last I checked (Dec 2018) it was working fine.

My only guess is that Cpanel has auto updates which updated some core passenger or ruby modules that affected this, but for the life of me I can't figure out what.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I’m not very familiar with this, but have you checked if the file permissions have changed? Maybe you need to chmod it.

Comment: Why, may I ask, cPanel?  https://forums.cpanel.net/styles/cpanel/cpanel/cP-logo.png

Comment: So this was a server that a client gave us (despite protest). Personally, I would've gone for a ubuntu install as I'm more familiar. @lacostenycoder

I don't think anything has changed which is the strangest thing. I've even redeployed it (via Capistrano) in case anything has changed but nothing works.

Comment: @bo-oz you're right, it's a permissions error. For some reason the public_html folder of cpanel (which is where I put my app) was changed to 750 so nothing could read it except for the group.

Answer (score 0):

So it was just cPanel changing permissions by itself it seems. My nginx user couldn't read the public_html folder as it was set to 750.